# Https in .net core web api app in docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I have ASP.NET Core Web Api application. Also I have (not my) remote `REST` service which is accessible by https using GOST algorithms. I'm doing `GET` request from my service to this secure remote service. To access remote server I have public and private parts of the key which are in `cer` and `pem` files. Moreover, my app is working in docker app. 
I can do request with curl from docker container:

```
curl https://someserver.com -v --cert /app/cert/certificate.cer --key /app/cert/privatekey.pem --insecure
```

But how can I do it using HttpClient? Or other class from my code?

After googling and experiments i'm at the point of view that this is not possible now using .net core 2.1 in such environment without third party libraries (i even didn't find any of them) or linux packets. I can't load pem file and i'm always getting SSL handshake error from code.

P.S. I'm using `rnix/openssl-gost:stretch` docker image for GOST support on linux.

Comment: You ever find a solution to this issue?  I'm having the same issue with .net core 2.2.  The following works in a Windows environment, but fails in a linux environment because `CspParameters` is Windows only and throws a Platform Not Supported error.  I have found no other way to set the private key KeyName, so the handshake fails.
```
//We must set the key container name or the handshake fails.  
CspParameters parms = new CspParameters();
parms.KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpperInvariant();

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parms);
```

Comment: @MikeB I'm still didn't find any good solution. I wrote curl.sh and calling it with parameters from my c# code using Process class. This solution is not beautifull but working and working very stable. There were no problems with this solution. If you are interesting in it I can share the curl.sh and calling code. Just let me know

Comment: No, I wound up getting what I needed from a different source using JWT auth. When I have time I was going to see if there was something that would work in .net core 3.x. If that endpoint is still active anyway.